# LUIS intent pattern matching

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I want to define an Intent that matches purely on a prefix. This only seems to work if the utterances have as many words as the ones I train it with.

For example, if I want an intent to match for anything that starts with "My name is" then if i train it with "My name is John Smith" and "My name is John" then it works fine if the utterance has 1 or 2 words but if the utterance is "My name is John X Smith" then it fails to categorize as the intent.

How can I define an intent with a variable number of words that appear after some selection of fixed prefixes?

Comment: How many examples have you provided to create this intent? if they are few (less than 10), you need to provide more examples with variable length to catch similar intents

Answer (score 0):

A [Pattern Feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-features#pattern-features) might be what you're looking for. It will take regex patterns which help when LUIS is parsing utterances.

Below is a screenshot from the LUIS documentation:

[image: MSCS_Screencap]